# How to add a column with string values of a dictionary in Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, kaggle

I am trying to add a column with values from a dictionary.

The DataFrame looks as follows with a total of 29 countries
[dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YovZ6.png)

My Dictionary looks as follows:

```
# Define a dictionary containing european Regions 
eu_regions = {'Central and Eastern Europe': ['Latvia', 'Bulgaria', 'Lithuania', 'Croatia', 'Czechia','Poland','Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Hungary'],
        'Northern Europe': ['Sweden', 'Norway', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Estonia'],
        'Western Europe': ['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Luxembourg', 'Netherlands', 'France', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Norway', 'United Kingdom'],
        'Southern Europe': ['Italy', 'Cyprus','Malta', 'Portugal', 'Greece', 'Spain']}
```

To add the new columns called "region", which is meant to add the region of each country I used following command.

```
eu_vaccine_df['region'] = eu_vaccine_df['country'].map(eu_regions)

eu_vaccine_df.head()
```

In the result however, the new column "region" is created but does not add the new country and fails to match the country to the region of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
country_dct = {}
for key, countries in eu_regions.items():
    
    for country in countries:
        country_dct[country] = key


eu_vaccine_df['region'] = eu_vaccine_df['country'].map(country_dct)

eu_vaccine_df.head()
```

Comment: You're a true Hero! Yes it worked. Thank you Lukas :)

Comment: Great that I could help out :)